# Array merge on the go

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I often start to define an `array`, and then figure out I need to break it up in two or more pieces. I would then start with `$array('key' => 'value')` for my first values and then having to rewrite the code for the other parts of the array like this:  `$array['key'] = 'value'`. But that's a hassle.

So I tried the following, that seems to work:

```
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array(
    'First day'     =>  'A Partridge in a Pear Tree',
    'Second day'    =>  '2 Turtle Doves',
    'Third day'     =>  '3 French Hens',
    'Fourth day'    =>  '4 Calling Birds',
);

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array_merge($my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas, array(
    'Fifth day'     =>  '5 Golden Rings',
    'Sixth day'     =>  '6 Geese a Laying',
    'Seventh day'   =>  '7 Swans a Swimming',
    'Eighth day'    =>  '8 Maids a Milking',
));

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array_merge($my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas, array(
    'Ninth day'     =>  '9 Ladies Dancing',
    'Tenth day'     =>  '10 Lords a Leaping',
    'Eleventh day'  =>  '11 Pipers Piping',
    'Twelfth day'   =>  '12 Drummers Drumming',
));
```

Is there a better/cleaner/faster way of doing merging an array on the go?

Comment: I suppose you could define all the arrays first and then only do one `array_merge()` at the end passing all arrays in.

Comment: merge all array at once..!

Comment: Why the downvote? I have done my research, I provide two possible solutions to the  problem, and ask a clear question on ways to improve it.

Comment: @OnklMaps don't pay attention to the downvote. Your question is perfectly viable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way seems to be:

```
$foo = [
    'First day'  => 'A Partridge in a Pear Tree',
    'Second day' => '2 Turtle Doves',
    'Third day'  => '3 French Hens',
    'Fourth day' => '4 Calling Birds',
];

$foo += [
    'Fifth day'   => '5 Golden Rings',
    'Sixth day'   => '6 Geese a Laying',
    'Seventh day' => '7 Swans a Swimming',
    'Eighth day'  => '8 Maids a Milking',
];

$foo += [
    'Ninth day'    => '9 Ladies Dancing',
    'Tenth day'    => '10 Lords a Leaping',
    'Eleventh day' => '11 Pipers Piping',
    'Twelfth day'  => '12 Drummers Drumming',
];

print_r($foo);
```

---

Reference: https://php.net/manual/language.operators.array.php

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand
>   array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the
>   left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the
>   right-hand array will be ignored.

Comment: Ah.. Perfect. In my case I would start with `$foo = array(key=>value)`, chop off 2/3 of the array and continue with `$foo += [key=>value]`. Very clean in my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

This is already clean in my honest opinion, but if you want to make the code cleaner, take a look at what is repeatedly causing difficulties. Define a helper function like this:

```
function addRange(&$mainArray, $range) {
    foreach ($range as $k => $v) {
        $mainArray[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Then you could simplify slightly your code:

```
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array(
    'First day'     =>  'A Partridge in a Pear Tree',
    'Second day'    =>  '2 Turtle Doves',
    'Third day'     =>  '3 French Hens',
    'Fourth day'    =>  '4 Calling Birds',
);

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

addRange($my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas, array(
    'Fifth day'     =>  '5 Golden Rings',
    'Sixth day'     =>  '6 Geese a Laying',
    'Seventh day'   =>  '7 Swans a Swimming',
    'Eighth day'    =>  '8 Maids a Milking',
));

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

addRange($my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas, array(
    'Ninth day'     =>  '9 Ladies Dancing',
    'Tenth day'     =>  '10 Lords a Leaping',
    'Eleventh day'  =>  '11 Pipers Piping',
    'Twelfth day'   =>  '12 Drummers Drumming',
));
```

Comment: I like this. It's strange though that this is not (?) a built in function for PHP. Must be a common thing to want to do.

Comment: @OnklMaps indeed, as far as I know this is not built-in and I agree this is a common thing one might want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to complicate it this way. This works too. Definitely a shorter version though:

```
<?php
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array(
    'First day'     =>  'A Partridge in a Pear Tree',
    'Second day'    =>  '2 Turtle Doves',
    'Third day'     =>  '3 French Hens',
    'Fourth day'    =>  '4 Calling Birds',
);

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Fifth day']     =  '5 Golden Rings';
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Sixth day']     =  '6 Geese a Laying';
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Seventh day']   =  '7 Swans a Swimming';
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Eighth day']    =  '8 Maids a Milking';

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Ninth day']     =  '9 Ladies Dancing';
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Tenth day']     =  '10 Lords a Leaping';
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Eleventh day']  =  '11 Pipers Piping';
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas['Twelfth day']   =  '12 Drummers Drumming';
```

The version that's better than the above is to define all the arrays somewhere and then use an `array_merge` at once.

```
$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = $chrismas1;

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array_merge($my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas, $chrismas2);

breathe(); // breathe, and then I want to continue my array where I left it.

$my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas = array_merge($my_true_love_sent_me_for_christmas, $chrismas3);
```

Comment: Any specific reason for voting down? This is just my opinion and better version than the previous.

Comment: I already mentioned the `$array['key'] = 'value'`-way of doing it. And how is defining the array somewhere else making it better? I was asking for a way to do it on the go.